# python tkinter draw over a current canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to implement Monty Hall with some GUI.

```
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=600, height=500)
square1 = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 500, 150, 200, fill="blue", tags="open_door_1")
square2 = canvas.create_rectangle(250, 500, 350, 200, fill="red", tags="open_door_2")
square3 = canvas.create_rectangle(450, 500, 550, 200, fill="green", tags="open_door_3")
canvas.tag_bind("open_door_1", "<Button-1>", door1)
canvas.tag_bind("open_door_2", "<Button-1>", door2)
canvas.tag_bind("open_door_3", "<Button-1>", door3)
canvas.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

It shows:

[image]

When you press each "door", it calls a different function.
I want that after every choice, a grey block will hide one of the doors (or something like that).
But I don't know how to manage the canvas, when I'm not in the 'main'.

currently my door1, door2, door3 functions are not doing much. Only checks if a random number suits the door number.

Would love some help.

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Have you searched this site for answers? Have you read the Canvas documentation?

Comment: Have you tried `canvas.update()`?